# i have been getting this error (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)) . i am trying to use Google maps API

Tags: swift

[image]I have been getting this error

> (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)) .

I am trying to use Google maps API

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyAvOP_l2nOnJX8ShskJHFNAPXB3wL93wNA")
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

Comment: the error line is (class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {)

Comment: This is not the actual line. Check the crashlog in XCode log section and please provide the log with your question.

Comment: could you take a look at the picture I just upload

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have missed to add **-ObjC** value to **Other Linker Flags** in project build settings.

Click to the Build Settings tab, and search for the **Other Linker Flags** setting. Once you spot it, add the **-ObjC** value to it, as we are going to bridge the maps SDK written in **Objective-C** with the Swift project we currently have.

[image]

Fore more you can check this: https://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/